# Passing Intent from one package to another

Tags: android, android-intent, package

I have to pass an intent from activity of one to package to another. For Example, have two package Package1 and Package2. Both Packages have two activities Activity1 and Activity2. I have to Pass an intent from Package1.activity1 to Package2.activity1. Thank You.

Comment: can you explain what do you mean package?

Comment: What is your problem? What do you mean by "pass an `Intent`"? Please be more specific or show your code and explain what isn't working as expected

Comment: Package mean Applications two Applications in same project

Comment: just do `startActivity()` as you would do normally

Answer (score 0):

I believe when you are talking about package u mean a separate module?

If so - you need to link one module to another;

To do so:
in `module1/build.gradle` add

```
implementation project(":module2")
```

After that you will be able to reach classes from `module2` in `module1`

Answer (score 0):

Not need of wondering about packages if you are using any IDE like Android Studio or Eclipse, Automatically required class of other package will be import in the Activity. Just use the below codes for intent.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Activity1.this, Activity2.class);
startActivity(intent);
```